# Initializing a global 2 D array with -1 in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, heap-memory, dynamic-programming

I Want to initialize a global 2d array with `-1`, currently, I'm able to declare a global 2d array and initialize it with `-1` in the main function by below approach;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int dp[10][100];

int knapsack(vector<int>wt,vector<int>val,int w,int n){
    if(w==0 || n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(dp[n][w]!=-1){
        return dp[n][w];
    }
    if(wt[n-1]<=w){
        return dp[n][w]=max(val[n-1]+knapsack(wt,val,w-wt[n-1],n-1), knapsack(wt,val,w,n-1))
    }
    else{
        return dp[n][w]=knapsack(wt,val,w,n-1);
    }

}
int main(){
    vector<int>val={60,100,120};
    vector<int>wt={10,20,30};
    int w=60;
    int n=val.size();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
            dp[i][j]=-1;
        }
    }
    cout<<knapsack(wt,val,w,n);
}
```

To initialize with -1 outside main function i tried to modify my code as below but it resulted in an error;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int dp[10][100];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
            dp[i][j]=-1;
        }
}
int knapsack(vector<int>wt,vector<int>val,int w,int n){
    if(w==0 || n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(dp[n][w]!=-1){
        return dp[n][w];
    }
    if(wt[n-1]<=w){
        return dp[n][w]=max(val[n-1]+knapsack(wt,val,w-wt[n-1],n-1), knapsack(wt,val,w,n-1));
    }
    else{
        return dp[n][w]=knapsack(wt,val,w,n-1);
    }

}
int main(){
    vector<int>val={60,100,120};
    vector<int>wt={10,20,30};
    int w=60;
    int n=val.size();
    cout<<knapsack(wt,val,w,n);
}
```

How to initialize my 2D array outside the main function, as sometimes we have to write just function and we are not able to modify code inside main. kindly looking for help.

Comment: Simple answer: Unless you specify *all* elements it's just not possible. Use a `std::vector` instead (where it becomes *very* easy, as there's a [constructor overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (number 3 in the linked reference) supporting it).

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of array. Then you can write: `std::vector<std::vector<int> > dp(10,std::vector<int>(100, -1));` globally or locally.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 10>` instead of `int[10][100]` ?

Comment: instead of storing some values `x` in the array you can store `x-1`, if you apply the same transformation to reading from the array, then it is "initialized to -1". Its not that nice, but globals and using a sentinal value to denote absense of a value arent either

Comment: @paolo That should be allowed, so much easier to pass arrays around without decay that way.

Comment: Why use a global anyway?  Initialize the array in main and just pass it to the functions that need it. Or make a class where the array is a member. Global variables have a tendency to become unmaintainable in bigger projects. Also don't use `using namespace std;` that too will bite you in big projects.

Comment: Did you implement knapsack and the contents, as well as the dp[][] array? If so, perhaps consider not using -1, but instead 0, then you can initialize using dp[10][100]={}; It is also quite strange you cannot modify main(), so assume a test/assignment, so they are forcing you to use a global, which is not great practice. You could initialize inside knapsack function also detecting first time called - also horrible. What a strange one.

Comment: @Chris Looks like something from leetcode (or other competitive coding site) which are known for their low quality C++ examples (to put it mildly)

Answer (score 3):

The array will take up a fixed place in memory anyway, so why not do the initialization at compile time instead of at runtime.
You can do this with a constexpr function template like this (C++20, requires constexpr std::array) :

```
#include <array>

template<typename type_t, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
static constexpr auto create_2D_array(const type_t& initial_value)
{
    std::array<std::array<type_t, M>, N> values;
    for (auto& row : values)
    {
        for (auto& value : row) value = initial_value;
    }

    return values;
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto values = create_2D_array<int,3,3>(-1);
    static constexpr auto value = values[1][1];
    static_assert(value == -1);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To directly initialize, you need to list the elements of it. However, to simply have the arrays filled with `-1`, you can use the `bool` initializer trick:

```
int dp[10][100];
 
const bool init_dp = []() {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
                dp[i][j]=-1;
            }
    }
    return true;
}();
```

`dp` and `init_dp` must be in the same compilation unit and in this order; then it's guaranteed that, after this point in the static initialization, `dp` will be filled with `-1`.

If you don't like the `bool` init trick, but ok to define an object to reach `dp`, you can get very similar behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename, typename>
struct AA {};
 
template<size_t... is, size_t... js>
struct AA<std::index_sequence<is...>, std::index_sequence<js...>> {
    int a[sizeof...(is)][sizeof...(js) + 1] = {{(int(js) * 0 - 1)..., int(is) * 0 - 1}...};
};
 
using DP = AA<std::make_index_sequence<10>, std::make_index_sequence<100 - 1>>; // NOTE: 100 - 1 = 99 is needed here
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(DP::a), int[10][100]>::value);
 
// now you can define DP dp; and use dp.a
 
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    DP dp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to compile your second snippet: I get `error: returning initializer list` once I instanciate `DP dp;`.

Comment: @paolo In that case, you can use `decltype(DP::a) dp;` (updated the answer as well)

Comment: Yes but then `dp` is uninitialized. I believe the problem is that `auto onedim(int dummy) { return {(js * 0 - 1)...}; }` doesn't compile.

Comment: @paolo You're right, fixing the code also helped me to simplify it.